# How to update hours, mins and seconds in Data using java?

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know, how to get date of a certain time zone and update hours , mins and seconds of it. For example

if EST time now is 20230710 05:22:22
I want to update it to 20230710 01:25:00  and also get previous date and set time to 20230709 01:25:00

Using below i am getting EST time , but I am not able update the hour,mins and secs
Please advise

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
long utc = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date currentTime = new Date(utc);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String s = df.format(currentTime).replace("-", "");
```

Comment: Stop using outdated classes like `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateformat`. Swith to the newer `java.time` API

Comment: Something like `ZonedDateTime then = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).withHour(1).withMinute(25).withSecond(0);`